# How to calculate sum of each row in 2D array and place in vector?

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate the sum of each row in the array and place it in a vector,
You can find my attempt below,

For that, it prints the same values for the first 4 and a different for the last 1, `215 215 215 215 316`

What I want is for example

```
x1 2 4 4 6 7  Sumx1=??
x2 1 2 3 4 5  etc
x3 1 2 3 4 5 
x4 1 2 4 5 6
```

and place the value Sumx1 in a vector.

Here's my attempt

```
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    srand(time(NULL));

    int pay[5][4];

    vector<string> names;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            pay[i][j] = rand() % 51 + 50;
            cout << pay[i][j] << "  ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    vector<int> totals;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            totals.push_back((pay[i][0] + pay[i][1] + pay[i][2] + pay[i][3]));
        }
        cout << totals[i] << "  ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For totals, you are both looping 0...3 AND calculating the sum of all columns at once.  So:  how many elements did your first loop of i add to totals?  Hint: not just 1.  How many elements does total have when you're done?  Hint: not 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        for(int c=0; c<4; c++){
            totals.push_back((pay[i][0]+pay[i][1]+pay[i][2]+pay[i][3]));
            }
        cout<<totals[i]<<"  ";
    }
```

Try removing the inner loop (the one with variable c). Should work.

Answer (score 0):

You add the sum `pay[i][0]+pay[i][1]+pay[i][2]+pay[i][3]` to the vector four times due to your inner loop c.

What you really want is the following,

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int c=0; c<4; c++)
        sum += pay[i][c];
    totals.push_back(sum);
    cout<<totals[i]<<"  ";
}
```